# Do these configuration changes suit my needs?

Tags: apache, configuration, php, httpd.conf

I want to get a reasonably large file (around 45-50M) from user of my application, and then move that file to some other server.

I have done following changes to configuration files, **can someone please comment how I have done, or if there are any changes, please suggest.**

**I want to know whether these changes fulfill my requirements (uploading large file without time) or not?**

Changes made to **php.ini** file

```
max_execution_time = 0
max_input_time = 900
memory_limit = 128M

upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 51M
```

Changes to Apache **httpd.conf** File

```
Timeout 1800
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you are OK with those values - but it would be almost comically easy for an attacker to DOS your site by smashing it with huge uploads (not an issue if this a private/intranet-type application)

Answer (score 2):

When a user uploads a file the following configuration values are important and should be set correctly:

- PHP

  - file_uploads
  - upload_max_filesize
  - max_input_time
  - memory_limit
  - max_execution_time
  - post_max_size
- Apache

  - LimitRequestBody

with the `LimitRequestBody`, on some RPM Installation this is set to .5MB, if thsi is set then you should remove this all together or if you have strict limit then you can set that.

I would also invest in using Node.JS behind Apache, and forward uploads to that process, this way you can reduce a lot of memory usage by installing a simple upload library.

When a file has been uploaded you can store the file in the temp, create a hash of it, and then redirect the client by sending back the `Location` header, this will then redirect the user back to the php process passing in the hash, where you can then locate and restore etc.